# Vim - omitting a colon when defining a command?

Tags: vim

In [`usr_40.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html), there are two examples of user-defined commands:

1. `:command -nargs=0 DeleteFirst 1delete`
2. `:command -nargs=+ Say :echo <q-args>`

Why does `echo` here require a preceding `:` while `1delete` does not?  What is the general rule here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

These are equivalent.

```
:command -nargs=0 DeleteFirst 1delete
:command -nargs=0 DeleteFirst :1delete

:command -nargs=+ Say :echo <q-args>
:command -nargs=+ Say echo <q-args>
```